# Wrong image size in loadad SVG with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I am trying to load an SVG file in canvas using fabric.js:

```
svg_url2 = "http://localhost/fabric/bozza biglietto-03.svg";

canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svg_url2, function(objects) {

canvas.add.apply(canvas, objects);
canvas.renderAll();
```

The SVG file has an inline image which is rescaled, but when it loads in canvas the image is rendered at its original size.
If I paste the same SVG in the kichensink demo, it's displayed with ist correct dimensions. Am I missing something?

The SVG:

[SVG image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2cdzf7x17asmcj/bozza%20biglietto-03.svg?raw=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svg_url2, function(objects, options) {
   var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});
```

I should work.

Comment: It does not work; I already tried that. Besides, it's not what I need since I want the objects to remain ungrouped.